# Poached by my client, and I want to accept, what do I say to my current employer?

Tags: job-offer, quitting, politics

I work as a Marketing Consultant within a small agency in Australia. I've been there for 4 years and recently was given the opportunity to manage the marketing account for a new client. After working with them for several weeks, my client started hinting he wants someone 'in house', and then he verbally offered me the role and the amount he offered was nearly double what I get paid! At first I was concerned about the situation so I kind of brushed off the conversation, but thinking about it more, I've realised that it's too good of an opportunity to miss.

I've always felt loyal to my current employee, but they do drastically under pay for this industry. There's nothing in my contract about this kind of thing, but I also don't want to ruin my relationship with my current employer, or my client. My questions are... What do I do next? How do I find out if it's a genuine offer, without risking my current role? And then how do I approach it with my employer? Thanks

Comment: Tell us how it goes.  There's a chance that the client is in cahoots with your employer to see who is loyal and who is a traitor, and the offer is fake.

Comment: @Jack, that sounds illegal.

Comment: And rather ridiculous. This is business, not spycraft: it's almost certainly still cheaper for the client to pay a high salary than it is to pay the agency commission.

Comment: `How do I find out if it's a genuine offer` - ask for an offer in writing and observe their response.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that there is nothing in your employment contract that prevents you from leaving, leave on as positive a note as possible, leaving the door open to a relationship of some sort that will be of possible benefit to him - If your employer has any wits about him, he will realize that he is better off not collapsing bridges with you and with your new employer. You are not going to put a good word in for your soon to be ex-employer if he smacks you on your way out. And don't mention the money aspect - he most probably can't compete with that, if you can at all avoid mentioning it.

Comment: Why not mention the money aspect? You don't need to go into details, but getting an offer with a much better salary is a very valid reason for leaving.

Comment: @jpatokal Do you want to rub it in? If you don't want to, keep quiet about it. Don't say another word about the money.

Answer (score 3):

Wait and gather more information.

Check the clients contract - they may be in breach by trying to poach you.

if this is all clear then ask your potential new employer for a draft employment contract and formal offer.  If the new offer is serious  the client will be happy to move it to the next step.  Just do all you can to make sure the offer is genuine and not some ploy.

Until it is in the bag - best not to mention at all to anyone - and keep it all verbal or using personal email.

Once you have some certainty - either genuine new job offer  or a hoax you are in a much stronger position to use this to your advantage.

Comment: The breach of a non-solicitation clause would be a problem for the client, not for the employee.

Comment: @Philipp if firing the employee in question would settle a breach lawsuit, then it could be a problem for the employee.